# (this).parent().find not working for getting response in ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, dom

```
$(".content-short").click(function() {
      $(".content-full").empty();
      var contentid=$(this).parent().find(".content-full").attr('data-id');
      var content=$(this).parent().find(".content-full");
      alert(contentid);
      var collegename = $(this).attr('data-id');
      $.ajax({
          type: "post",
          url: "contenthome.php",
          data: 'collegename=' + collegename,
          dataType: "text",                  
          success: function(response) {            

            $content.html(response);
          }
      });
    });
```

here the alert displays the specific data-id but

```
content=$(this).parent().find(".content-full");
```

this didn't displays data in content-full div with that specific data-id
anything wrong in the code or something else?

the query displays data if i use(."content-full"); instead of

```
$(this).parent().find(".content-full");
```

Comment: Please share your markup.

Comment: @MeeneshJain, yes but it isn't deleting the element...

Comment: What do you expect the value of `$(this).parent().find(".content-full");` to be?

Comment: empty(); in the start of the query is for clearing out previously fetched data it does not conflict with the problem @MeeneshJain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside the ajax callback you are using `$content`, but you declare your variable as `content`. May that be the problem? 
Your question is not clear. What are you trying to achieve?